# OpenLayers 6 - Custom Marker not displaying

Tags: openlayers, markers, openlayers-6

I'm created a map and have placed a marker. The only marker I can get to work is one hosted from OpenLayers. I have my own marker in "img/marker.png" but it doesn't display? Any ideas? I've tried moving it to the root folder and using "./img/marker" without success.

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import {Icon, Style} from 'ol/style';
import {Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';

const ukCenterLonLat = [-4.5, 55];
const ukCenterWebMercator = fromLonLat(ukCenterLonLat);

const GYLonLat = [1.728, 52.5982];
const GYWebMercator = fromLonLat(GYLonLat);

const iconFeature = new Feature({
  geometry: new Point(GYWebMercator), //This marker will not move.
  name: 'Great Yarmouth',
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        features: [iconFeature]
      }),
      style: new Style({
        image: new Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 46],
          anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
          crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
          // src: "marker.png",
          src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/icon.png'
        })
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: ukCenterWebMercator,
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```

Comment: I have tried lots of different methids I've come across, but nothing seems to solve me issue.

Comment: Have you tried placing your image on a publicly available web server?

Comment: No, not something I have tried, but I've seen people reference images locally using a relative link. I'll try that later.

Comment: It seems to work for me with a public image if I remove the `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'`, not sure why that should be (there are other examples that work with that there): [fiddle (using the legacy build)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pzmh64jk/4/)

Comment: I have the same problem.  I May need to talk to OpenLayer directly